# Why is the content of QNAME field NOT the original domain in a DNS message?

Tags: algorithm, networking, dns, udp, wireshark

Why is the content of QNAME field **NOT** the original domain in a DNS message?

For example, if I want to get the IP of domain `www.mydomain.com`, I will send a DNS lookup package to the network, and the package's question section contains the domain.

But actually **the content of QNAME in the package** is **`3www8mydomain3com0`** instead of `www.mydomain.com`.

`3www8mydomain3com0` means every label begin with the length of this part and then content, end with length of 0.

So, Why do we use length+data pattern to describe a domain rather than original domain?

Have a look at this section `4.1.2. Question section format`describes how we define the domain record on [RFC1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) (Please search to see this section).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Domain names changed to get Stack Overflow to shut up about the domain that cannot be named.)

> For example, if I want to get the IP of domain [www.qqqqsovr.com](http://www.qqqqsovr.com), I will send a DNS lookup package to the network, and the package's question section contains this url.

That's not a URL, it's a domain name.  A domain name is *part* of a URL, but a URL would be something like `http://www.qqqqsovr.com/homepage.html`.

> But actually the content of QNAME in the package is `3www8qqqqsovr3com0` instead of `www.qqqqsovr.com`.

That *is* `www.qqqqsovr.com`.  As Calle Dybedahl said, it's because the names are encoded in a somewhat complicated form.  Section 3.1 "Name space definitions" of [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) says:

> Domain names in messages are expressed in terms of a sequence of labels. Each label is represented as a one octet length field followed by that number of octets.  Since every domain name ends with the null label of the root, a domain name is terminated by a length byte of zero.  The high order two bits of every length octet must be zero, and the remaining six bits of the length field limit the label to 63 octets or less.

and those individual bits of the name can be pointed to by other names, so, for example, if you had both `www.qqqqsovr.com` and `www.abcdefgh.com` in a DNS message, the second domain name could point to the `.com` of the first domain name; this is described in section 4.1.4 "Message compression" of RFC 1035.

Simply putting the domain string into the messages as a text string wouldn't allow compression; you'd need *some* way to express pointers.  You'd probably have to ask [Paul Mockapetris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Mockapetris) why he (and Jon Postel) chose to use that *particular* encoding.

And even there the string length has to be indicated *somehow*, either by a count or by null-termination.  In 1987, whilst UNIX machines were common on the Internet, they weren't, as far as I know, *so* common that null-termination was an "obvious" choice.

Comment: Thank you, I made a mistake, I have fixed the question. But main problem here is why we use length+data to describe a domain rather than original domain?

Comment: Look at this section 4.1.2. Question section format on http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1035 . It describes the detail record of a query package.

Comment: That section is short and doesn't discuss name encoding.  I've expanded the answer to give more information on why length+data might have been chosen.

Answer (score 1):

1) DNS knows nothing of URLs. DNS is older than the concept of a URL.

2) Because that's how DNS's wire format works. What you see is the domain name `www.mydomain.com`, encoded in the DNS binary format. Length+data is a very common way of storing strings in general.

Comment: Could you tell me why length + data is a common or useful way to store strings?

Comment: The alternative is to have a magic value that terminates the string, which means that either the strings cannot contain the magic value (as is the case with normal C strings and NULL) which removes functionality, or you need some kind of quoting, which adds a lot of complexity.

Comment: There are two most common conventions of string.. Null-terminated strings and length-prefixed.. Null-terminated is used as default in C, Length-prefixed are default in Pascal. DNS names choose length-prefixed strings, because you can access subdomains without changing original string (without add terminator behind subdomains) and subdomains will keep valid length-prefixed format