# Reading DNS packet in python

Tags: python, dns

[This question had been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977588/reading-dns-packets-in-python) but the question was never fully addressed, and is from 2013. I am using python sockets to observe DNS packets, they appear like so:

```
b'\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03www\x10googletagmanager\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01'
```

Upon researching the fundamentals of DNS packets, I found they are structured like so:

> QR | OpCode | AA | TC | RD | RA | Z | AD | CD | RCODE

I then decoded the packet to ASCII:

```
>> str = b'\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03www\x10googletagmanager\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01'
>> print(str.decode("ascii"))
wwwgoogletagmanagercom
```

This only returns a single string with the name of the address, and not other info as specified above. Where is the rest of the data, like the QR and OpCode? Am I decoding it incorrectly?

To be clear, I do not want to use an external library and my aim is to understand how DNS packets are structured and how to decode them; I am aware of libraries such as `dnslib` and `scapy`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reading DNS packets in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977588/reading-dns-packets-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a socket expert.  From reference - DNS header is made up of bits not bytes... so you need to parse it as bits.  Use bytes and mask bits. See sample below.   It unsure what contents of header hdr[12:] is?

Here is some sample code based on above spec:

```
def DNStoDict(hdr):
    '''
    Parse QNAME by using length (byte) +data sequence -- final length=0 signifies end of QNAME
    Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34841206/why-is-the-content-of-qname-field-not-the-original-domain-in-a-dns-message

    1) DNS knows nothing of URLs. DNS is older than the concept of a URL.

    2) Because that's how DNS's wire format works. What you see is the 
       domain name www.mydomain.com, encoded in the DNS binary format. 
       Length+data is a very common way of storing strings in general.
    '''

        # Build DNS dictionary of values... include QNAME
    l = len(hdr)
    argSize = hdr[10]*256+hdr[11]
    dnsDict = dict(ID     = hdr[0]*256+hdr[1],
                   QR     = bool(hdr[2] & int('10000000', 2)),
                   Opcode =     (hdr[2] & int('01111000', 2))>>3,
                   AA     = bool(hdr[2] & int('00000100', 2)),
                   TC     = bool(hdr[2] & int('00000010', 2)),
                   RD     = bool(hdr[2] & int('00000001', 2)),
                   RA     = bool(hdr[3] & int('10000000', 2)),
                   Z      = bool(hdr[3] & int('01000000', 2)),
                   AD     = bool(hdr[3] & int('00100000', 2)),
                   CD     = bool(hdr[3] & int('00010000', 2)),
                   RCode  = bool(hdr[3] & int('00001111', 2)),
                   QDCOUNT = hdr[4]*256+hdr[5],
                   ANCOUNT = hdr[6]*256+hdr[7],
                   NSCOUNT = hdr[8]*256+hdr[9],
                   ARCOUNT = argSize,
                   QTYPE   = hdr[l-4]*256+hdr[l-3],
                   QCLASS   = hdr[l-2]*256+hdr[l-2])

    # Parse QNAME
    n = 12
    mx = len(hdr)
    qname = ''

    while n < mx:
        try:
            qname += hdr[n:n+argSize].decode() + '.'

            n += argSize
            argSize = int(hdr[n])
            n += 1
            if argSize == 0 : 
                break
        except Exception as err:
            print("Parse Error", err, n, qname)
            break
    dnsDict['QNAME'] = qname[:-1]
    return dnsDict

# Sample DNS Packet Data 
hdr = b'\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03www\x10googletagmanager\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01'


# Parse out the QNAME
dnsDict = DNStoDict(hdr)


print("\n DNS PACKET dictionary")
print(dnsDict)
```

#### OUTPUT:

DNS PACKET dictionary
{'ID': 257, 'QR': False, 'Opcode': 0, 'AA': False, 'TC': False, 'RD': False, 'RA': False, 'Z': False, 'AD': False, 'CD': False, 'RCode': False, 'QDCOUNT': 0, 'ANCOUNT': 0, 'NSCOUNT': 0, 'ARCOUNT': 3, 'QTYPE': 1, 'QCLASS': 0, 'QNAME': 'www.googletagmanager.com'}

### Pyhon Bit Manipulation

Refer to

1. https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation
2. http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Python/Data_Types/How_to_create_integer_in_Python_octal_binary_hexadecimal_and_long_integer.htm

A byte (`b'xxxx'`) represents 4 bytes.  Each byte is made up of 8 bits

0000 0000 - 0
0000 0001 - 1
0000 0010 - 2
0000 0100 - 4
0000 1000 - 8
0001 0000 - 16
0010 0000 - 32
0100 0000 - 64
1000 0000 - 128
1111 1111 - 255 (128+64+32+16+8+4+2+1)

### In python the format int('00000111', 2) is convert an array of strings ['0'/'1'] using modulo 2 (bits).  This returns value 7 modulo 10.

Reference DNS Header:
https://www2.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall16/compsci356/DNS/DNS-primer.pdf
http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/dns.htm

[image]
[image]

Comment: Great! This is what I was after. Could you explain specifically the usage of  `& int('10000000', 2)` and why the binary value varies on each slice of info?

Comment: added some additional info... enjoy!

Comment: How can I extract the qname without the surrounding x00\x00\x01\x00\x01'?